# Add custom CSS class to element `.ck-content` in CKEdtior5 and Vue2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, ckeditor5

How to add custom CSS class to element `.ck-content`, by other words, to editable formatted text container in CKEditor5 and Vue2?

[image]

The `ck-content` is the input field; we must differ it from the toolbar above, the other part of CKEditor. So if we want to apply some class affecting only to inputted content, it must not affect to toolbar.

Seems to be obvious solution:

```
<ckeditor class="CustomClass" :editor="editor" v-model="editorData" :config="editorConfig"></ckeditor>
```

will not work because `CustomClass` it will not be applied to `.ck-content` and even not to root element.

Below solution will not work too, because when `CKEditorWrapper` mounted, the `CKEditor` mounting has not complete yet.

```js
import CK_EditorVueAdaptation from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue2";

@Component({
  components: {
   ckeditor: (CK_EditorVueAdaptation as { component: VueClass<unknown>; }).component
  }
})
class CKEditorWrapper extends Vue {
  private mounted(): void {
    this.$el.getElementsByClassName("ck-content").item(0) // null
  } 
}
```

Comment: こんにちは Some thoughts: from the document I see there are some events for the component, to be triggered in different stages, like [this](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/vuejs-v2.html#ready). Have you tried to add a function in the @ready event handler, and use JavaScript's `document.querySelector` to find the DOM node, then add your custom class?

Comment: @マークさん, Thank you for the comment! I suppose "ready" is the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue CKeditor component emits `ready` event when it's really mounted and rendered. So an easy solution: catch it and add the class to the wanted node, having in mind that `this.$el` is the sibling of the real container of the editor.

```
<ckeditor
  ...
  @ready="onEditorReady"
/>
...
,
methods: {
    onEditorReady () {
      const myClass = 'anyCustomClass'
      const addCustomClass = () => this.$el.nextSibling
        .querySelector('.ck-content')
        .classList
        .add(myClass)

      this.$nextTick(addCustomClass)
    }
  }
```